# M2eclipse dependency resolution

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I notice that m2eclipse doesn't automatically add transitive dependencies to a project's build path...

For instance, if "Project A" specifies "Library X" as a dependency which, in turn, depends on "Library Y", I cannot use "Library Y" in "Project A" unless I **also** explicitly specify "Library Y" as a dependency the pom.xml.

Is this by design? Or a flaw in m2eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly does add transitive dependencies. Note it's now called **m2e**. Your dependencies need to be specified in the POM. If you're not used to Maven, you might be adding the dependencies by hand using Eclipse's build path tools. You don't need to do this any more. Just right click on the project and do Maven -> Update Project... and it will sort out the build path for you.

Comment: It turns out the error was that I was trying to use the "RELEASE" maven-version of a dependency. For whatever reason, it downloaded a pretty old version of the library (contrary to what it seems "RELEASE" version should have downloaded). Everything that depended directly on that library was fine, but when I needed to use something from its dependencies, I was getting "org.thatlibrary... not found" errors. Either way, I'm now refraining from the whole "latest/release" version specifications, and manually specifying them. Now all the transitive dependencies are getting found just fine...